# How to open UDP port in kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-networking

I have a DeepStream application running inside a Kubernetes pod. The applications captures video from a camera using the RTSP protocol. The pod is not able to establish a UDP connection between the camera and the pod.

> Could not receive any UDP packets for 5.0000 seconds, maybe your
> firewall is blocking it. Retrying using a tcp connection.

I posted the same on the DeepStream [forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/not-getting-stream-from-a-depepstream-application-running-insde-kubernetes/268509/14)

The following is the response:

> The log shows the SDP session is successful. But the client failed to
> receive any data from the UDP port. Please check the UDP port(normally
> it should be 554).

How to open a UDP port on Kubernetes?

Kubernetes manifest file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: detection-pipeline
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: detection
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: detection
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: deepstream-detection
          image: localhost:32000/detection:v2
          command: ['python3', 'app.py']
          # command: ['sleep', '6000']
          env:
          - name: KAFKA_SERVICE
            value: kafka-service
          - name : API_ENDPOINT
            value: 'http://va-application:8000'
          - name : PORT
            value: '5000'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: models-storage
              mountPath: /app/model_zoo  # Mount path for static files, adjust as needed

      volumes:
        - name: models-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: models-pvc

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: detection-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: detection
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with Kubernetes, but have you tried replacing `protocol: TCP` with `protocol: UDP`?

Comment: `protocol: TCP` its for flask application and not for camera communication.

Comment: Then add both if you need TCP and UDP